# How to compile avconv with libx264 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin)?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, ubuntu-12.04

Is there a step-by-step guide on how to compile *avconv* in Ubuntu?

It seems hard to search for any tutorial with *avconv* compared to *ffmpeg*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally found out how,

1.) Make a directory avconv-source

```
mkdir avconv-source
```

2.) Download and install the x264 library

```
cd ~/avconv-source
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git x264
cd x264
sudo ./configure --enable-static
sudo make
sudo make install
```

3.) Download the avconv source

```
cd ~/avconv-source
git clone git://git.libav.org/libav.git avconv
cd avconv
sudo ./configure
sudo ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264
sudo make
sudo make install
```

and now you can execute

```
avconv -i test.mov -c:v libx264 -c:a copy test.mp4
```

Comment: When I run `sudo ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264` I receive an error: `avconv-source/avconv/libavcodec/libx264.c:412: undefined reference to 'x264_encoder_open_125'`

Comment: @JJD you probably have two different versions of x264 installed simultaneously (this includes the libx264-dev package). Try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directory where libx264 is supposed to be, got this answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838456/undefined-reference-to-x264-encoder-open-125

Comment: Thank you. I followed the guide on [how to install FFmpeg on Ubuntu Precise](http://delicious.com/redirect?url=http%3A//ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) and it works for me somewhat. I use this command: `ffmpeg -i in.mts -vcodec libx264 -filter:v yadif -s hd1080 -ab 128k -strict -2 -threads 0 ./out_x264.mp4`

Comment: `configure` on `avconv` didn't work for me, I repeatedly got the error `ERROR: libx264 not found`. configuring `x264` with `./configure --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-pic` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 9):

It worked great for me on Ubuntu 12.04, except that it complained that assembler was missing.

The minimum version is yasm-1.2.0.
If you really want to compile without asm, configure with --disable-asm.

Thanks to *[HOWTO: Install and use the latest FFmpeg and x264](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11404469)*, I did the following as well, and it was OK beyond that.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall

sudo apt-get build-dep yasm

wget http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-1.2.0.tar.gz && \
tar -xf yasm-1.2.0.tar.gz && cd yasm-1.2.0 && ./configure

make

sudo checkinstall --pakdir "$HOME/Desktop" --pkgname yasm --pkgversion 1.2.0 \
--backup=no --default
```

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 13.04 and Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.

```
apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
```

Comment: This is [`libavcodec-extra-54`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libavcodec-extra-54) on Ubuntu 14.04.